# QModelIndex to QJSValue

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I try to reimplement the `filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent)`-method of a `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

Here I want to call a callable `QJSValue` and pass the two parameters to it. For this I need to have them in a `QJSValueList`, which is easy for the integer.

But I fail to find the method to do the same with the `QModelIndex`.

- There is no constructor of the `JSValue` that takes a `QModelIndex`
- `QJSEngine::createQObject` takes a QObject, which I don't have.

Do I have any chance on succeeding?

**EDIT: WHAT I TRIED NOW**

```
bool FilterModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
{
    if (m_filter.isCallable()) {  // check whether a JS-Function is set
        QJSValueList l;
        QJSValue f = QJSValue(m_filter);
        l << QJSValue(source_row);

        // **** ADD MORE USEFULL STUFF HERE ****
        // This is working now - thanks to your help. But useless in QML
        QJSEngine *engine = m_filter.engine();
        l << engine->toScriptValue(source_parent);// <-- Value is of no use in QML. Can't do anything with it. And for ListModels as source utterly useless

// V----- To add this would make more sense, but the app crashes. Don't call index()!!!     
//        l << engine->toScriptValue(index(source_row, 0, source_parent));
        return f.call(l).toBool();
    }
    // If no JS-Function is set, fall back to the original method
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent);
}
```

Please forgive me any trivial errors. Its 5 years since I last used (and started to learn) C++.

Comment: `QModelIndex ` is directly used in `DelegateModel` which means you should be able to wrap it up in a `QVariant`.

Comment: Yeah, it is possible to wrap it in a `QVariant` but I still fail to get a `QJSValue` out of it. There is no `toQJSValue()` or a `QJSValue`-Constructor that takes a `QVariant` either. `QVariant` is also no `QObject`, so I still cant pass it to the `QJSEngine::createQObject`-factory.

Comment: Why? What you plan on doing with it? You can only have QJSValue for QObject references and primitive types. More is not necessary.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsvalue.html#call <- `QJSValue QJSValue::call(const QJSValueList &args = QJSValueList())` takes a `QJSValueList`. I want to pass the `source_row` and the `source_parent` to a *callable* `QJSValue.call`-function. This function is exposed as `Q_PROPERTY`, so I can set a JS-Function in QML to define the filter. Like this I have more options than just filtering with *one* RegExp on *one* role.

Comment: Well, you could always write your own conversion function that creates a JS object which includes the desired model index members. The way it looks, the model index is an opaque type in QML - you can pass it around, but it is not directly usable from JS code. So you will have to convert manually.

Comment: Have you tried [QJSEngine::toScriptValue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsengine.html#toScriptValue) ?

Comment: I also implemented it in my still undertested and underdocumented library https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel/ . The usage would be `filters: ExpressionFilter { expression: /* an expression that evaluates to a bool. You can access roles and index here like in a delegate */ }`

Comment: `QJSEngine::toScriptValue` seems to work, but the passed object has seemingly no content at all. At least, none that I would know how to access... Just passing the object to `console.log` tells me I succeeded: `qml: QVariant(QModelIndex)`. But I can't use it at all... So I will see what useful information I can extract in a usable format, and pass this instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're doing from your description, but assuming you have a `QModelIndex` (in C++) and want a `QJSValue` for some reason, then I think `QJSEngine::toScriptValue` is indeed what you want. This should probably be linked from the `QJSValue` doc, I'll try fix that for a future release.

I've never done this myself, but something like this should work:

```
QJSEngine *e; /* I assume you've got this already somewhere .. */
QModelIndex m = something->index(...); /* and you have a model index */
QJSValue val = e->toScriptValue(m);
// go ahead and use val!
```

If you want to go the other direction, that is, unboxing a QModelIndex from a QJSValue:

```
QJSValue val = something->prop(); // now to extract it...
QModelIndex m = e->fromScriptValue<QModelIndex>(val);
// go ahead and use m!
```

Both `QVariant` and `QJSValue` are sort of dynamic "boxes" that can contain different types of data, so you don't want to double up and give QML what amounts to `QJSValue(QVariant(QModelIndex))` (won't compile, just to demonstrate storage), because it won't know how to unbox it properly.